# Ruby (Sequel): filtering by date (year) and attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, select, sequel

Using Sequel, I need to find all documents that are created in `2012` and have a title `@title`.

```
$dataset = DB[:documents]
$dataset.select(:title).where(:created_at.extract(:year) => 2012, title: @title).all
```

But this returns nothing instead of returning two documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what database you are using, but if you are using SQLite, you need to set `DB.use_timestamp_timezones = false` and clean up all timestamps in the database to remove the timezones.  Sequel defaults to using timezones on SQLite, but SQLite's date/time functions don't recognize timestamps with timezones.

If you aren't using SQLite, you should provide more details about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just wrote `title: @title` instead of `:title => @title` , and also verify that `@title` is the same type as title

Comment: It looks fine at the moment, what I would try doing is cutting it into pieces.
Trying out the command without the .select() at the beginning. If that doesn't work try remove one of the conditionals. for instance try only by year, or only by title, see what is the culprit in your SELECT statement. If you have any idea, bring it forward and I'll try to help

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 `title: @title` is the same as `:title => @title`.